# Value of a field of Java object dynamically (by reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

I get names of various fields in a class like this :

```
Field[] f = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
Sring str = f[0].toString();
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
```

Now I want to access the (public) field `str` from the object `cl` dynamically. How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`Field.get`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method like this (for the 0th field):

```
Object x = f[0].get(cl);
```

To figure out which index the `str` field has you can do

```
int strIndex = 0;
while (!f[strIndex].getName().equals("str"))
    strIndex++;
```

Here's a full example illustrating it:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class MyClass {
    String f1;
    String str;
    String f2;
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field[] f = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
        MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        cl.str = "hello world";

        int strIndex = 0;
        while (!f[strIndex].getName().equals("str"))
            strIndex++;

        System.out.println(f[strIndex].get(cl));

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello world
```

Comment: But how will I get the context of object cl?

Comment: I previously thought that you meant a static method.

Comment: Better yet, use `MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("str")`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Field f = Myclass.class.GetField("Str");
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
cl.Str = "Something";
String value = (String)f.get(cl); //value == "Something"
```

Comment: This is what I used. Not sure why you would want to get all the fields and loop through them to find the one you're looking for. `GetField()` is a much cleaner approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Should go like this:

```
Field[] f = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
MyClass targetObject = new MyClass();
...
Object fieldValue = f[interestingIndex].get(cl);
```

Mind the exceptions.